# Add Subtotals by Group to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I find myself trying to accomplish something  with pandas that I often do with R data.table.  I think the best way I can unambiguously describe what I want is by showing the analogous R operation:

```
fruit <- rep(c('apples', 'oranges'), 2)
date <- rep(c('2017-07-01', '2017-07-02'), each=2)
count <- 1:4

dat <- data.table(date, count, fruit)
```

the dat variable now houses data that looks like this

```
         date count   fruit
1: 2017-07-01     1  apples
2: 2017-07-01     2 oranges
3: 2017-07-02     3  apples
4: 2017-07-02     4 oranges
```

Suppose I want to add up all the counts by date, call this "fruit" "total" and add it to the original data.  To achieve this in R, I might do this (I think this isn't the most elegant way, but I'm not asking for R help right now...)

```
dat.total <- rbind(dat[, list(count=sum(count), fruit='total'), list(date)],
                   dat)
```

And sure enough dat.total looks like this:

```
         date count   fruit
1: 2017-07-01     3   total
2: 2017-07-02     7   total
3: 2017-07-01     1  apples
4: 2017-07-01     2 oranges
5: 2017-07-02     3  apples
6: 2017-07-02     4 oranges
```

So...I'm trying to do this with pandas and I just can't figure it out.  Here's as far as I've gotten:

```
import pandas as pd

fruit = ['apples', 'oranges'] * 2
date = ['2017-07-01', '2017-07-01', '2017-07-02', '2017-07-02']
count = [1, 2, 3, 4]

dat = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': fruit, 'date': date, 'count': count})
```

So far, so good.  Here's dat:

```
   count        date    fruit
0      1  2017-07-01   apples
1      2  2017-07-01  oranges
2      3  2017-07-02   apples
3      4  2017-07-02  oranges
```

Some googling got me this far to get the sums for each date:

```
agg = dat.groupby('date').sum()
```

But this is already problematic.  agg seems like a fundamentally different *thing* than dat.  (To put a finger on one specific piece of what I mean, agg.index is the date column, whereas dat.index is a default RangeIndex)

I can't figure out how to add a "fruit" column with "total" for each value, and even if I *could*, I don't know that I could easily concat these things because of the different indices / columns.

Seems as though my approach is all wrong, but I'm having a hard time even figuring out what to google.

Just to be extra clear about what exactly I'm trying to do: I'm hoping to get a pandas DataFame which is similar in spirit to the R transformation I showed at the beginning.  I guess the *TL;DR* is that I'm trying to go from:

```
         date count   fruit
1: 2017-07-01     1  apples
2: 2017-07-01     2 oranges
3: 2017-07-02     3  apples
4: 2017-07-02     4 oranges
```

to

```
         date count   fruit
1: 2017-07-01     3   total
2: 2017-07-02     7   total
3: 2017-07-01     1  apples
4: 2017-07-01     2 oranges
5: 2017-07-02     3  apples
6: 2017-07-02     4 oranges
```

A first step of `agg = dat.groupby('date').sum()` seems promising, but I have no idea where to go next or if this is already headed down the wrong road.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a combination of `groupby`, `append`, and `assign`

```
df.groupby('date')['count'].sum().reset_index() \
    .assign(fruit='total').append(df, ignore_index=True)

         date  count    fruit
0  2017-07-01      3    total
1  2017-07-02      7    total
2  2017-07-01      1   apples
3  2017-07-01      2  oranges
4  2017-07-02      3   apples
5  2017-07-02      4  oranges
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  My reputation is too low for my upvote to matter and the site is telling me that it's too soon after I asked the question to "accept" your answer, but I'll set a timer to come back and do so in a few minutes!

Comment: @HarlandMason while I appreciate the sentiment... the timer is there for a reason.  If someone comes in with a better answer within the 15 minutes, then by all means, they should get the accepted answer.  Secondly, you now have the rep to up-vote (-:

Comment: Thx @ScottBoston!